# In Gwt, how to make the little hand pop up when using ClickHandler for Label

Tags: gwt, label

Say, I don't like to use Anchor or Hyperlink, but prefer to use Clickable Label.
But After add ClickHandler for Label, & when I mouse over, there no little hand popup as we often see when using HyperLink or Anchor. So,

how to make the little hand pop up when using ClickHandler for Label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can acheive that in two ways:

**With Gwt alone**

```
           lable.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);
```

**and by adding css style to the `lable`(preffered)**

```
lable.addStyleName(mylableStyle);


.mylableStyle {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: No need for the _mouseover_, and the second approach is generally preferred.

Comment: Yeah as thomos said,acheiving through css is always prefferable.

Comment: Actually the mouseover solution in this case is doesn't make sense and should not be used as such. The cursor is something that becomes visible on mouse over, but that doesn't mean you need to have a mouse over to set the cursor. Just use the code inside the `onMouseOver` method directly to set the cursor or (preferred) the css solution.

Comment: @Hillbrand Bouwkamp yeah edited and said css is prefered solution :)